# CQRS Projection One-To-Many / Many-to-Many

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

Let's assume i want to create a sports event Event-Sourcing Project with CQRS.

- A Team as many players
- A Game has 1 winner
- A Game has 2 Teams
- A Game has n Events (Points are added, Fouls, Timeouts, etc.)

How would i create the projection for that?

**Game with Winner**

| GameID | Location | TeamNameOne | TeamNameTwo | Winner | PointsTeamOne | PointsTeamTwo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Munich | Avengers | Suicide Squad | Avengers | 48 | 30 |

But how would i design the Team has many players projection?
With a JSON Field?

| TeamID | TeamName | Players |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 432 | Avengers | [{"name": "Man, Iron", "number": 34}, {"name": "America, Captain": "number": 1}...] |

Or with a line for each player?

| TeamId | TeamName | PlayerId | PlayerName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 432 | Avengers | 34 | Stark, Tony |
| 432 | Avengers | 1 | America, Captain |

The same with Events for each Game, that could be much, depending on how granular i want to track each activity.

I thought about a DocumentBased Database for the Events in a Game, so each Game could include all the activities in one Field (Like in the Players-Column for the Teams). But then it would get complex too, because *Game* contains *Acitvity* contains *Acitvity's Player*

Is a GraphDB like Neo4J better for that? I think, but then i have to start creating "queries" and the projectors are not independent anymore.

And then the question for the Aggregate design. Because i am not sure if i should add a List of Player IDs in a TeamAggregate and a List of Events for a Game.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking... are you asking about where to store events?  If you're asking about which DB and model to use for the projections, the basic answer is that you can use a different DB for each projection if that's what fits (a denormalized document store is often a reasonable choice)

Comment: For a list of events for a game, there's probably no point in storing that in a game aggregate: if you need it, you can just query/filter the events.

Comment: Sorry, that it has not been clear enough. The question is, how to store a List of different Game Moves (Goal, Foul, etc.) in the Projection.
The Projection should not need joins but should be "ready to view" for the client.

But yeah, a denormalized Document store would be great.

Comment: At first i thougt, if i want to add "Fans" to a Team, the denormalized Team-Document would get huge. But The Fan-Stuff could be stored somewhere else, in a Neo4J or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this issue a lot myself, and it seems to me that the more 'read-optimised' you want, the more data you have to store (and the more complex the writing becomes).

Your point about each activity containing a copy of the user record is a great example.

You could imagine on the front-end, that there is a tool-tip for each activity that happens, which when the user hovers over the tool-tip displays a link to that particular player and their profile picture.

Having that read-model 'ready-to-view' would mean potentially copying user data many times into each event.

Then if a user changes details (like a new profile picture), then you have to iterate over large data structures and update the new value across the board.  This adds a lot of complexity to making updates to this projection.

In terms of how to store this data, I'd probably go with a key-value document.  I find those well suited to displaying on a front-end because they form a hierarchal tree, which is the same as HMTL, so there is a natural mapping between the two.

Like many things in software, there are trade-offs.  The less joining and more 'ready-to-view' you want the data, the more data duplication and more complexity of keeping consistency.

You can make the joins cheaper by using key-value stores (as they have near constant lookup time).

So you could have this type of structure:

```js
{
  gameId:'sdk',
  gameEvents: [
    {
      playerId: 'abc',
      eventType: 'FOUL',
    }
    // etc.
  ],
  players: {
    abc: {
      name: 'billy',
      profilePicture: 'billy.png',
    },
    // etc.
  }
}
```

Then all your front-end has to do, is each component where the tool-tip is rendered, you can do like:

```html
<div>
  <tooltip>
    <content> {{ event.eventType }} </content>
    <hover> {{ data.players[event.playerId].name }} </content>
  </tooltip>
</div>
```